# Why and how is the hash-sign (number-sign or pound-sign) used in this VBA statement

Tags: vba

I am trying to understand code written by someone else, and I came across this>

```
...
dtStart = #1/1/2022#: Range("I3").Value = dtStart
...
```

I understand that hash, or number, is used in type declaration double, but this?

Anyone know?

Answer (score 1):

That is just how dates are represented in vba.

```
    Dim x As Variant
    x = "1/28/2022"
    
    
    Debug.Print x, VarType(x)
```

returns string type.

```
    Dim x As Variant
    x = #1/28/2022#
    
    
    Debug.Print x, VarType(x)
```

returns date type.

```
    Dim x As Variant
    x = 1 / 28 / 2022 'This is NOT the date as a double, it is dividing
    
    
    Debug.Print x, VarType(x)
```

returns double type.

A date in VBA is just a fancy double so it makes sense that it would be wrapped in `#`.

If you take a look at the conversion function [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/type-conversion-functions) you can see converting a string to a date isn't recommended. Instead it recommends using these date literals.